# Yii relational database with not working

Tags: php, yii

I have this piece of code on my UsersController

```
$userModel = Users::model()->with('userSubscriptionTypes')->find(array(
            'order'=>'userSubscriptionTypes.idUserSubscriptionType DESC',
            'limit'=>1,
            'condition'=>'t.paypal_profile_id=:paypal_profile_id', 
            'params'=>array(':paypal_profile_id'=>'I-S09AAFCLHH57')
        ));
```

This is giving me error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'userSubscriptionTypes.idUserSubscriptionType' in 'order clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`idUser` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`username` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`password` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`email_address` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`firstname` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`lastname` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`isAdmin` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`paypal_profile_id` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`date_created` AS `t0_c8` FROM `users` `t` WHERE (t.paypal_profile_id=:paypal_profile_id) ORDER BY userSubscriptionTypes.idUserSubscriptionType DESC LIMIT 1
```

It seems the `with` is not working basing on the SQL code snippet that the error gave.

This is the `Users.php` relations Model code:

```
public function relations()
{
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'trackedItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TrackedItems', 'idUser'),
            'userSubscriptionTypes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserSubscriptionType', 'idUser'),
        );
}
```

What is wrong with this one? And ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Just try `'order'=>'idUserSubscriptionType DESC'`, for order clause. And make sure you have column `idUserSubscriptionType` in your selected table.

Comment: Actually, I already tried that one, but still there is that error.

Comment: Can you check your query by outputting it ?

Comment: This is the query that is outputting: SELECT `t`.`idUser` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`username` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`password` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`email_address` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`firstname` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`lastname` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`isAdmin` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`paypal_profile_id` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`date_created` AS `t0_c8` FROM `users` `t` WHERE (t.paypal_profile_id=:paypal_profile_id) ORDER BY userSubscriptionTypes.idUserSubscriptionType DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: `idUserSubscriptionType` in which table you have this column ?

Comment: the name of the table is user_subscription_type

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29708/discussion-between-rikesh-and-elson-solano)